# Why is Scala's Set.subsets() method defined as an empty-paren method?

Tags: scala, set, parentheses, side-effects

Scala's immutable `Set` class has a method called [`subsets()`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#subsets():Iterator%5BC%5D) that returns all the subsets of a set.

Usually empty-paren methods are reserved for methods that cause side effects, but this one doesn't seem to.

Why isn't this method defined as a parameterless method? Does it in fact cause some side effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9116

Because `subsets` is overloaded. There used to be a type inference issue if one overload has no parens. I don't know if that type inference issue still exists, but the parens which were added as a workaround are still there.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer, but could you expand on how the parentheses would fix the inference issue? I don't find it very clear from the linked issue.

Comment: Looks like this PR is where the change was actually introduced https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4309

Answer (score 3):

Because they return a mutable iterator to the set of subsets, so processing the iterator will have side-effects. Each call to `subsets()` will therefore also create a different iterator, so

```
someSet.subsets() != someSet.subsets()
```

which suggests that the call is not *referentially transparent*.

See also [this discussion](https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/issues/520) about a similar method (`iterator()`) on another collection type (`IterableOnce`).

Comment: That's a good argument and makes sense, but I think the actual answer is the one given by @Jasper-M; the method was originally parameterless and the parentheses were added to help type inference.

Comment: @Ian That's debatable. If you read [Martin Odersky's comment](https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/issues/520#issuecomment-375586799) in the discussion, omitting parentheses would violate the _uniform access principle_ (it's this that makes parentheses necessary). I don't dispute that the parentheses were added to fix a type inference issue, but they should have been there in the first place. Still, your call... ;-)

Comment: It is indeed debatable, as there didn't seem to be a big consensus about Odersky's statement :-P And the eventual conclusion of the discussion was to not add parentheses to methods like `iterator`.

Comment: @Ian Fair point. ;-)